# Genymotion unable to load VirtualBox engine on Windows 10

Tags: android, windows, android-emulator, virtualbox, genymotion

I recently upgraded to Windows 10 BUILD 10130 and for some reasons, Genymotion doesn't seem to be working. It says "Unable to load VirtualBox Engine."

Now i did a bit of research and all the solutions suggested to **Delete the Host-only network** from Virtual Box settings. Well here's the thing i don't have any networks listed there. And the one which i found on the **Network and Sharing center** cannot be deleted.

Even a clean install hasn't solved the issue

Please help.

Comment: are you able to start virtualbox?

Comment: Yes, I am. VirtualBox starts up but I cannot find and **host-only networks** to delete ( that is the recommended solution )

Comment: Is it working with the new Genymotion 2.5?

Comment: No it does not work with Genymotion 2.5. It actually creates the host-only adapter, but then fails at some point after that. I believe it is a virtualbox problem not genymotion. If you try to create a host-only adapter directly in virtualbox it also fails. I tried VirtualBox 5 RC 2 and same thing.

Comment: did you resolve this issue? I am facing similar problem after updating to Windows 10

Comment: @RainMan can you pls try my solution below, I got this problem with Win 10, too. Hope that can help

Comment: I solved this issue. It's working fine now.
------------------ Please check here: [http://stackoverflow.com/a/32101818/2294050](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32101818/2294050)

Answer (score 40):

Step 1: Run VirtualBox as administrator

Step 2: Go to File -> Preferences -> Network -> Host Only Networks

Step 3: Add a new one or just edit an old one (if not work, **delete all existed and create a new one**):

```
Adapter Tab:
    IPv4 Address:        192.168.x.201
    IPv4 Network Mask:   255.255.255.0
DHCP Server Tab:
    Server Address:      192.168.x.100
    Server Mask:         255.255.255.0
    Lower Address Bound: 192.168.x.101
    Upper Address Bound: 192.168.x.199
```

Comment: This fixed the problem that Genymotion wouldn't start. But the emulators now seem to have no internet access (e.g. Browser).

Comment: I cannot even launch VirtualBox that came with Genymotion on Windows 10 at all.  Regradless if administrator or not.  The app doesn't launch.  Period!

Comment: Actually, the solution to my issue is to completely install new VirtualBox from Oracle **DIRECTLY**, not from Genymotion site.  Then everything works without modificaton.

Comment: "install new VirtualBox from Oracle DIRECTLY, not from Genymotion site." THAT is the only thing that actually fixed it for me! Thank you.

Comment: This worked for me -- installing Virtual Box directly from Oracle -- and adding a new Host Only Network.  But to add the Host Only Network I had to go into the "Global Tools" tab or click on File > Host Network Manager.  The Network tab did not allow me to add a Host Only Network

Answer (score 11):

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9pd7ZtO-87A - here video solutions for this. It just helped me. I use this settings for VirtualBox Network:

```
Adapter Tab:
    IPv4 Address:        192.168.1.201
    IPv4 Network Mask:   255.255.255.0
DHCP Server Tab:
    Server Address:      192.168.1.100
    Server Mask:         255.255.255.0
    Lower Address Bound: 192.168.1.101
    Upper Address Bound: 192.168.1.199
```

UPD: My Virtual device starting only form Genymotion app. But show mistake if I try to start it from Android Studio

Answer (score 9):

I had the same problem on my Windows 10 Insider Preview (Build 10130).
But fixed it by running **Genymotion** using *right-click -> Run As Administrator*.

Comment: This. This. This.

Comment: Just install both apps as an administrator.

Answer (score 5):

My this problem solved by first start **Virtualbox** as Administrator and then **Genymotion** also start as Administrator :) happy coding :)

Answer (score 4):

None of the above solutions or any solutions in any other thread/forum worked for me.

Here's what I did to solve the issue

1. Uninstall VBox and Genymotion
2. Install Genymotion again from the website with VirtualBox (124mb for Windows) https://www.genymotion.com/#!/download
3. Restart PC
4. Try to load Genymotion, you should get the same error again
5. Open RegEdit go to HKEY_CURRENT_USER > SOFTWARE > Genymobile > Genymotion
6. Check for the key 'VBoxPath'. In my system this path was

> C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\\VBoxManage.exe

7. Edit the path to remove the double '\' It should now be :

   > C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxManage.exe
8. Save changes and start Genymotion!

Worked like a charm for me :)

Comment: The re-install worked, but the registry edit wasn't necessary in my case.

Comment: just add registry key to path you say worked for me, i do not install any things, just add registry path, Win10 X64, VMbox 5.0,

Comment: I just edit registry key and add network card. It's works, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Only solution that worked for me is:
 1. Uninstall oracle vm virtual Box 5.0.4 and install 5.0.20(https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Download_Old_Builds_5_0)
 2. Run virtual box as administrator
 3. Run Genymotion as administrator
That's it.

Answer (score 1):

Genymotion 2.6.0 and Win10 didn´t start for me, got a error dialog when trying to start device in Genymotion. Tried to start the device from VirtualBox but got an error there to.

This solved it for me. Go to network settings in Windows and find your Virtual Host-Only Network that your device is using and select properties, if the VirtualBox NDIS6 Bridged Networking Driver isn´t selected the device will not start.

Answer (score 1):

To date, VirtualBox is not yet fully compatible with Windows 10. As Genymotion relies on the use of VirtualBox in the background, some problems may arise. If you have any troubles running Genymotion on Windows 10, we first recommend that you put VirtualBox in a clean state. To do so:
Uninstall VirtualBox.
Reboot your computer if prompted by the installer.
Install the version of VirtualBox recommended for Windows 10
Reboot your computer if prompted by the installer.
Open VirtualBox and go to File > Preferences > Network.
Remove all existing host-only networks by clicking Description 1.
Start Genymotion a first time.
In the event of a failure, start Genymotion a second time.
If Genymotion still doesn’t run, you can manually configure a host-only network:

Open VirtualBox and go to File > Preferences > Network.
Add a new host-only network by clicking Description 1.
Edit its configuration by clicking Description 1.
In the Adapter tab, set the following values:
IPv4 Address: 192.168.56.1
IPv4 Network Mask: 255.255.255.0
In the DHCP Server tab, set the following values:
Check Enable Server.
Server Address: 192.168.56.100
Server Mask: 255.255.255.0
Lower Address Bound: 192.168.56.101
Upper Address Bound: 192.168.56.254

[> genymotion.com](http://genymotion.com)

Answer (score 0):

In RegEdit on path: `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Oracle\VirtualBox` changing the value for `InstallDir` to `C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox` solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

These soutions doesn't work for me. But I found my solution.
So my solution: Go to computer BIOS, and enable "Virtualization Technology", and "VT-d".
After these, no need to changed the Virtual Box settings, but it will work.

Answer (score 0):

I try all guide but cannot fix, so I open genymotion > preference > ADB > set sdk path to my sdk path that I am using for build my app. It worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

Another good suggestion from the Genymotion's web site FAQ is to install the last version of VirtualBox. That worked for me, together with some other suggestions pointed out here (run as admin, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

Just an addition.

There are some conflicts between MayType and VirtualBox(above version4.1.32),so if you are using Mactype, you can open you mactype folder,find MayType.ini,and add these lines.If you have no WRITE authority to this file, just change authority setting.

```
[UnloadDll]
vbox-img.exe
VBoxBalloonCtrl.exe
VBoxDTrace.exe
VBoxExtPackHelperApp.exe
VBoxHeadless.exe
VBoxManage.exe
VBoxNetDHCP.exe
VBoxNetNAT.exe
VBoxSDL.exe
VBoxSVC.exe
VBoxTestOGL.exe
VBoxWebSrv.exe
VirtualBox.exe
```

Answer (score 0):

Installing the latest VirtualBox(5.1.8) solve the problem for me, while I have to turn off Hyper-V on windows as well.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing worked for me, is by removing all host-only networks, and start the Genymotion, it will auto re-configure the host-only networks for you.
Here are the steps for more details:
Open VirtualBox and go to File > Preferences > Network. Remove all existing host-only networks. 
Start Genymotion a first time. In the event of a failure, start Genymotion a second time.

Answer (score 0):

just uninstall Genymotion and VirtualBox then reinstall Genymotion(with virtualbox) , it will work.

Answer (score 0):

I installed Docker on my machine and it requires Hyper-V, I found the solution here : https://support.genymotion.com/hc/en-us/articles/360002732677