# genymotion "unable to load virtualbox engine" on windows 10 and Virtualbox error " Result Code: E_FAIL (0x80004005)"

Tags: android, windows, android-emulator, virtualbox, genymotion

I recently upgraded to Windows 10 , Genymotion doesn't seem to be working. It says "Unable to load VirtualBox Engine."

Now i did a bit of research and all the solutions suggested to Delete the Host-only network from Virtual Box settings. Well here's the thing i don't have any networks listed there. And the one which i found on the Network and Sharing center cannot be deleted and when i try to create a new one on virtualbox , it fails .

Even a clean install hasn't solved the issue

here is the screenshot of the problem.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/qwVLh.png

Comment: so you have a problem with running some application? ... off-topic ... it is not connected with programming

Comment: but i need it for android studio

Comment: try look advices from this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30951147/genymotion-unable-to-load-virtualbox-engine-on-windows-10/31720721#31720721

Answer (score 7, accepted):

genymotion.exe -> Properties -> tab Compatibility -> In Compatibility mode, check Run this program in compatibility mode for and selected Windows 8 -> check Run this program as an administrator -> Ok

Hope it will solve your problem.

Comment: This solution without checking run this program as an administrator step worked for me, thanks.

Comment: Thanks this worked for me as well.  This has been blocking me for a while

Comment: No this won't work if you have incompatible versions of virtual box & genymotion

Answer (score 4):

I had installed Genymotion + VBox package, and was having the same problem.
Running in compatibility mode didn't work for me, but this did:

1 - Uninstall VBox. Install latest version.

2 - Download Genymotion without VBox. Install Genymotion.

Comment: Worked for me and I think it's the cleanest solution.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and just solve it.

uninstall Genymotion and VM VirtualBox and download the full package not from [here](https://www.genymotion.com/#!/download)

The old version has some problems with windows10 that have been solved in the last update.

that works for me.

Answer (score 2):

Reply from (I had the same problem and just solve it.
uninstall Genymotion and VM VirtualBox and download the full package not from here
The old version has some problems with windows10 that have been solved in the last update.)

I always keep downloading in this site (https://www.genymotion.com) in which I always encountered error in file (unable to load virtualbox engine).
But after I read your comment, I decided to look for latest genymotion and virtualbox from other site. And it works perfectly. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I just solved the problem. You'll need to uninstall both Virtual Box and GenyMotion from your PC.You'll have to download the complete package(Genymotion + Virtual Box) from the Genymotion site.

Simply install both of them from the same package. And it will solve your problem (:

Answer (score 0):

Reinstalling Virtualbox worked for me.