# Genymotion error after windows 10 upgrade

Tags: android, genymotion, windows-10

Genymotion is giving me this error after the Windows 10 upgrade:

> Unable to load virtual box engine

How to fix this?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

### I solved this issue. It's working fine now.

I'm using:

```
+ Window 10
+ VirtualBox-5.0.2-102096-Win
+ Genymotion-2.5.3
```

**Step 1**: We should set **Run as this program as an administrator** & **Compatibility mode Window 7** for those file.

```
C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox
    + VBoxHeadless.exe
    + VBoxManage.exe
    + VirtualBox.exe
C:\Program Files\Genymobile\Genymotion
    + genymotion.exe
```

**Step 2**: My Computer -> Manage-> Device Manager-> Network adapters

Remove all items with name: VirtualBox Host-Only Ethenet Adapter #...

**Step 3**: Open Virtual Box and go to File -> Preferences -> Network -> Host Only Networks

Remove all and create new host with information:

```
Adapter Tab:
    IPv4 Address:        192.168.1.201
    IPv4 Network Mask:   255.255.255.0
DHCP Server Tab:
    Server Address:      192.168.1.100
    Server Mask:         255.255.255.0
    Lower Address Bound: 192.168.1.101
    Upper Address Bound: 192.168.1.199
```

**Step 4**: Run Genymotion again. It's will work.

### [=====> You can see here](http://s1187.photobucket.com/user/bjngboong/slideshow/Genymotion)

Comment: +1 for the slideshow, awesome job. No need to re-install, this method works perfectly. Edited post to change step 3 a bit to make it more clear.

Comment: I had to restart Genymotion a couple of time, but in the end this worked, thanks a lot!

Comment: you saved my day (night ) :D (y)

Comment: This worked for me but I also had to completely disable UAC (using msconfig.exe) and reboot

Answer (score 6):

I used to have the same issue. I've download VirtualBox 5 an reinstall it (or repair) **over the old install**. Reboot and that's it.

Answer (score 0):

Worked for me:

-Changed Network on VB to **HOST ONLY**

-Changed on Win 10 network configuration to obtain **dynamic IP**

Answer (score 0):

1.Remember machine images' paths/locations in VirtualBox. Bakup them.

2.Go to
[enter link description here][1]http://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/2087-hyper-v-virtualization-setup-use-windows-10-a.html

Only part two.Follow those instructions.

3.remove machines from VirtualBox(but dont check 'delete  files'). Remove adapters from 'network adapters' in device manager. Thier name starts with 'Virtual...'.

Close VirtualBox.

4. start genymotion.

Will work.

Answer (score 0):

After **Windows Anniversary update** **Genymotion** stopped working,

It always raised an error dialog saying (not exact but something like this) "*Failed to start the virtual machine, Please start Virtual box to see the error details*".

I had tried many solutions some of them were saying **open Virtual box** and make some changes to it, but my issue was **Virtual box itself was not starting up explicitly**,

I had observed that process starts up and gets killed after few seconds, Then I realized, the problem is actual with a virtual machine.

And when I was looking for it I came across this thread which says there is [Bug in the virtual box](https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/14519), just download and install the latest setup file for a Virtual box. Thereafter at least you will be able to start the virtual machine,

After this, if you face some issue you can follow a[**Loi Ho** answer above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32101818/1206052)